# Does last hitting provide more experience?

Tags: dota-2

I know last hitting gives you the gold for the kill, but what about experience?

Is there any difference between last hitting a creep or standing next to it, in regards of experience? What about Heroes and structures?

Comment: Only in the sense that if you last hit a creep it can't be denied, so you're guaranteed to get full experience from that creep.

Comment: You get experience from last-hitting towers and buildings, so in that sense, yes it does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Last hitting creeps gives you no extra experience. Experience is shared equally among all heroes that were the enemy of that unit in a 1500 area, even if they're already level 25 or if they never even saw the unit. An exception to this is if you are outside of the experience AoE. If you're farther than 1500 away and kill it, then you will get a share of the experience where you normally wouldn't.

Heroes give experience to all people in a 1500 area based on the number of people and the fallen hero's level as well as extra experience to the person that last hit them based on a somewhat complicated formula. [A table of the AoE experience and the formula are in this wiki page.](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Experience)

Comment: A good answer, but you wrote a lot about gold, which didn't interest the asker, and forgot to mention that towers give experience.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: doh >.<

Comment: > "If you're farther than 1200 away and kill it, then you will get a share of the experience where you normally wouldn't." This is only true for hero kills, not for creep kills.

Comment: What is with hero denies? If oppossing hero has a DoT on him, and is denied, does your team still get XP, or nothing at all?

Comment: @AntonRoth: Denied heroes give nothing to the other team at all.

Answer (score 2):

**No**,last hitting doesn't provide bonus experience as it does bonus gold.

If it did,the carries would outlevel their supports very quickly,which is not the case unless support gets out of exp range for pulling/stacking/warding.

Common misconception are denied creeps that divide 18 exp to enemy heroes within 1200 range  rather than 62\41 exp...it makes it look like you get less exp because you lose the last hit.

More on [experience](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Experience) and [last hitting/denying](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Creep_control_techniques)

Answer (score -1):

Here is another point of view:
In the loading screen it says the opposite:
"Dealing the last hit on an enemy creep gives you extra gold and experience" or words to that effect.

Patch 6.8x - I read the tooltip at 14th - august - 2014

Comment: I can't find any other sources that back this up, or any mentions of a change in recent patches (which would surely be widely discussed, because it would change *a lot* about how the early game is played for many heroes). Is it possible you misread it? It could also be an erroneous tip, and could be worthy of a bug report if it's confirmed to be incorrect.

Comment: The tooltip in the loading screen was clear to me, just stating what I read.

Comment: I changed the answer to reflect that I have an additional information as opposed to that it's set in stone.

Comment: [Here's the list of loading screen tips](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213559/is-there-a-file-will-all-the-loading-screen-tips-for-dota2). The tip in question is currently "Striking the last hit on a creep or hero will earn you additional gold."